# Multiple JSTL parameters with JavaScript

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have this JavaScript function in a JSP page

```
function loadXMLDoc (voteType){

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();

}
else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        alert ('arriva qua');
        if (xmlhttp.status = 200){

            alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
            if ('ALREADY_VOTED_UP' == xmlhttp.responseText) {
                alert ('You already voted up for this question');
            } else if ('VOTING_SUCCESSFULL' == xmlhttp.responseText) {

                if (voteType=='UP'){
                    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById('upvoteCount').innerHTML);
                    document.getElementById('upvoteCount').innerHTML = total + 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                alert ('Your vote can not be saved');

            }
        }
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("POST", "VotingAnswer");

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


xmlhttp.send ("answerId=${answer.id}" + "questionId=${question.id}&type="+voteType);
}
</script>
```

with this button I send the data to the servlet

```
<button type="submit"><img width="20px" height="20px" src="assets/img/Hands-Thumb-Up-icon.png"></img></button>
```

This is `VotingAnswer` servlet

```
Long answerId = 0L;
Long questionId = 0L;
questionId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("questionId"));
answerId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("answerId"));
```

but it gives me an error of that kind associated to answer.id parameter in the servlet

`java.lang.NumberFormatException:`

which means that i have no value associated with this parameter

so if I put only 2 parameters in the in the `xmlhttp.send` everything works fine

```
xmlhttp.send ("questionId=${question.id}&type="+voteType);
```

what am I doing wrong? 
seems like I have no data associated to the parameter `answer.id`, but that's no true because if I use the jsp button and form everything works fine... it's just a problem of JavaScript syntax maybe, I really don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You have a typo - missing `&` - you should have & before `questionId` like this -  `xmlhttp.send ("answerId=${answer.id}" + "&questionId=${question.id}&type="+voteType);` otherwise it gets concatenated like this answerId=123questionId=232 hence `NumberFormatException`

Comment: is still not working!! i don't know why it told me that the parameter answer.id is null with the javascript and is != null with jsp !!! i'm going crazy!

Comment: Just add javascript alert that will display ${question.id} and ${answer.id} before sending, as probably some of these values could not be found, and its hard to tell since its only a part of the page.